# Pytest: Create reusable code in conftest.py

Tags: duplicates, constants, pytest, fixtures, reusability

Due to the way pytest works, it is not possible (or recommended) to import other modules in a pytest module. Instead, one should properly edit it's `conftest.py` file.

Several times, I am put in a situation where I need to share constants/functions to several tests modules. And fixture fails to be as practical as functions. Even if they can be indirectly parametrized with the `indirect` parameter, they are still situations where it's not possible, or simple, to use this approach.

For constants, I am in the following situation, here is an extract of my `conftest.py`:

```
TARGET_NAME_1 = 'MY_OP4510'
TARGET_NAME_2 = 'MY_ML605'
TARGET_NAME_3 = 'TARGET_WITH_CHILD'
CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'

@pytest.fixture()
def target_name_1():
    """This fixture returns a target name"""

    return TARGET_NAME_1


@pytest.fixture()
def target_name_2():
    """This fixture returns a target name"""

    return TARGET_NAME_2

@pytest.fixture()
def target_name_3():
    """This fixture returns a target name"""

    return TARGET_NAME_3

@pytest.fixture()
def target_config_path():
    """This fixture returns the config path"""

    return CONFIG_FILE_NAME
```

Every time I have to add a constant, I have to add a fixture. Also, this increase the number of parameters the tests functions will receive (if in this case, I could use the `autouse` parameter, for some other fixtures that actually execute code, I do not necessary want to auto-use them as they could prevent other test cases from working).

I am looking for a way to simplify this code, would you have a good pattern/implementation to suggest ?

Comment: Not sure why it is not recommended to import other modules in tests. You have to import at least the tested function, and I regularly use utility functions in tests. Can you point to the documentation you refer to?

Comment: Why cant you have py file with all the constants and call them in your test. e.g say a `data.py` with `class MyData` having class variables  `TARGET_NAME_1 = 'MY_OP4510'` . in your test.py , you can import as `from data import MyData` . For your tests you can then call it as MyData.TARGET_NAME_1.

Comment: Yes I can import files from the tested software. But I cannot import modules from the test package. This is because one should NOT have __init__.py files in a folder containing tests files. This is not a good practice in any pytest version, but it can even be breaking since pytest 6.0. See how pytest import tests modules for reasons why: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/pythonpath.html

Comment: Can you create a fixture that returns an enum of constants?

Comment: I like the idea but python does not really have enums, I could create a class and return that class using the fixture, then access it's contants. A bit unusual but I guess it would do the trick

Comment: why do you need more than 1 fixture for that?and why don't you return dataclass in one fixture for all of the required that type of data tests?